# Redirect from Identity Server 4 not working on .net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, openid, identityserver4

I am following a Pluralsight.com tutorial from Brian Noyes called openid and oauth2 securing angular apps.

The exercise files work fine. When I updgrade the Identity Server (STS) to the newest asp.net core 2.2 framework, the redirect after logout gets stuck on the Start key discovery request from the DiscoveryKeyEndpoint

[image: ASP.NET Core Identity Server Console Application]

The error message on the console in chrome is the following

[image: Error message on Chrome]

When we look at fiddler it becomes obvious that there is something wrong with the content type that is being returned.

Here the working example with the correct content type of **application/json** and the old **ASP.NET Core 1.0 Application**

[image: Working fiddler Redirect Header]

And here the broken example with the incorrect content type of **application/jwk-set+json** and the new **ASP.NET Core 2.2 Application**

[image: Broken fiddler Redirect Header]

How do I fix this weird content type that is being returned.

Comment: package.json -> dependencies -> oidc-client: 1.5.1 on the Angular Client. Is that what you are asking me? I dont have oidc-client-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/609) that describes what's going on here. Essentially, a bug was introduced into `oidc-client-js` that caused the `Content-Type` header returned from the jwks endpoint to be valid only if it was `application/json`.

The issue was fixed in 1.5.2, so upgrading to that will resolve the issue you're seeing. The project is called `oidc-client-js` but the NPM package is [`oidc-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-client).